# How to convert excel VSTO add in in to a .xll to add directly through the excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

I need a help to understand VSTO addin vs the .xll excel addin .
what is the difference between both addins? 
Is there any possibility to convert VSTO excel addin into a .xll file to directly attach in an excel worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XLL Add-ins

XLL add-ins are the older native-code add-ins created via the [Excel Software Development Kit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/welcome-to-the-excel-software-development-kit). These add-ins are written in `c/c++` and make use of COM interop.

### VSTO Add-ins

Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) add-ins are the contemporary method to create Excel add-ins via managed code such as `C#`.  Microsoft provides a managed API instead of raw COM to access Office products including Excel.

OP:

> Is there any possibility to convert VSTO excel addin into a .xll file to directly attach in an excel worksheet?

Yes and no.  You would need to re-write the add-in not just to use c/c++ instead of .NET but also to use the COM API instead of the VSTO managed libraries.  Sadly there is **no** easy way to do this.

Comment: Thank's  @MickyD . Can u tell me that how can i deploy vsto add in directly from excel without installing a setup from my machine is there any possibility ??

Comment: @AteebKayani thanks.  That sounds like a _new_ question - feel free to post it.  To get you started checkout https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1666d2b0-a4d0-41e8-ad86-5eab3542de1e/deploying-office-solutions-to-end-user-computers?forum=vsto.  In saying that, the Visual Studio _tick-a-checkbox-make-me-an-installer_ ClickOnce option is the easiest . It requires zero coding and **doesn't require admin-rights** unlike other installer tech.  Are any form of installer an issue for you or your work?